# How do I collapse a user-topic network graph to a user-user graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph-theory, force-layout

I have a d3 force directed graph that shows a user-topic relationship. I want to collapse it into a user-user graph.

[image]
My node data looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": "USER",
    "type": "u",
}, {
    "id": "USER",
    "type": "u",
}, {
    "id": "USER",
    "type": "u",
}, {
    "id": "TOPIC",
    "type": "t",
}, {
    "id": "TOPIC",
    "type": "t",
}]
```

And my edges data looks like this:

```
[{
    "source": "TOPIC",
    "target": "USER",
    "score": 5
}, {
    "source": "TOPIC",
    "target": "USER",
    "score": 48
}]
```

How would I go about collapsing the graph?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this task before, so this is more a warning of potential pitfalls than an answer, but it might be useful and it won't fit in a comment.

The main point is you would need to build a new set of edges, but there's some non-trivial decisions / assumptions that need to be made.

Firstly sort then divide your current set of edges by topic. Then the set of users mentioned within each topic edge set should be connected to each other in your user-user graph as they share a topic. Your first problem now is what should you do with the scores in the original data set, do they mean anything now? What is the strength of link between the two users for that piece of edge data you mention above? 48 + 5? (48 + 5) / 2? Unknown?

Once you do this for more than one topic you'll then get multiple edges between the same users to occur if they have more than one topic in common. So what do you do here? Keep the individual edges, which will need some method of differentiating them both in the data set (they'll need different ids that incorporate topic as well as user ids) and visually, as with the default layout the edges will overplot each other. Or you could then merge edges between users for different topics, but again how do you calculate your score? Simple +1 for each added link? Some formula based on the links individual scores?

The good news is you don't need to do anything to the node set. The users are already there, just filter out the topics.